# Jenkins websphere deploy plugin fail when I try deploy it to different servers

Tags: jenkins, websphere, jenkins-plugins

i use jenkins to deliver an app into multiple servers to continuous integration and deployment. My Back-end is WAS and i have 3 servers (Dev, SQA, PROD) for scalability in the development and test of my proyects.

Im  using websphere deploy plugins to execute the first task and all is working fine when i deploy on server 1 (Dev), but i when to want execute the second task for deployment to server 2 (SQA) this proccess fail to ssl certificate. I have checked and the certificate is in the keytool.

After a lot of testing,  i restarted the Jenkins server and i executed the task to server 2 and after it finished i executed to  server 1,  now, the server 1 show the error but the task in server 2 works fine.

please help me with the soluction of this problem

this is the error:

```
Connection failed: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException: ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to host 172.20.234.107 at port 8880. 
at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClientPrivileged(AdminClientFactory.java:635) 
at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.access$000(AdminClientFactory.java:127) 
at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory$1.run(AdminClientFactory.java:210) 
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:63) 
at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(AdminClientFactory.java:206) 
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere.services.deployment.WebSphereDeploymentService.connect(WebSphereDeploymentService.java:388) 
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere_deployer.WebSphereDeployerPlugin$DescriptorImpl.doTestConnection(WebSphereDeployerPlugin.java:379)
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(Unknown Source) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:343) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:117) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:129) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) 
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:135) 
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:126) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) 
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:49) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) 
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84) 
at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51) 
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87) 
at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117) 
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87) 
at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125) 
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87) 
at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142) 
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87) 
at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271) 
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87) 
at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93) 
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87) 
at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249) 
at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67) 
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87) 
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76) 
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) 
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544) 
at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) 
at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClientPrivileged(AdminClientFactory.java:457) 
... 75 more 
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorNotAvailableException: [SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Error opening socket: java.io.IOException: Exception during sslSocket.startHandshake: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; targetException=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error opening socket: java.io.IOException: Exception during sslSocket.startHandshake: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target] 
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.reconnect(SOAPConnectorClient.java:429) 
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.<init>(SOAPConnectorClient.java:228) 
... 80 more 
Caused by: [SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Error opening socket: java.io.IOException: Exception during sslSocket.startHandshake: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; targetException=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error opening socket: java.io.IOException: Exception during sslSocket.startHandshake: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target] 
at org.apache.soap.transport.http.SOAPHTTPConnection.send(SOAPHTTPConnection.java:475) 
at org.apache.soap.rpc.Call.WASinvoke(Call.java:510) 
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient$4.run(SOAPConnectorClient.java:387) 
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118) 
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.reconnect(SOAPConnectorClient.java:372) 
... 81 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a WAS ND server? If so, you must point the plugin to the deployment manager's SOAP port which is typically 8879. Try upgrading to v1.5.6 as well and choose "Trust SSL certificates".